# Embedding .rh 3d models in html for interactive display

Tags: javascript, 3d, html5-canvas, chm

I have to embed the 3D models (format: right hemisphere) in the HTML page (WebHelp). The 3D player has to be embedded in the page/browser, rather than being a pop-up page.
In other words, to act like a YouTube video player embedded in the HTML page, showing a lightweight splash screen or multimedia thumbnail, that you can turn into full screen.

I am not able to follow on how to use the SAP VisualEnterpriseViewer to accomplish this. Otherwise, can we use javascript for this purpose? I know that jsc3d does not support .rh format yet.

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No one can support .rh format, except RH/SAP.  It is a closed, proprietary format.  And forget about html5, canvas, webgl etc.  These are too open, SAP / RH have traditionally created data silos rather than working off of open standards.

SAP VEV , formerly DeepView, does have a complete JS interface.  The viewer doesn't have to be a popup.  Look in the docs, you can embed the viewer in a page, and disable all the menus etc through appropriate javascript calls.  The docs are distributed with the viewer sdk, however it is getting rather hard to come by now.  Also helpful, and included with the docs, are examples.

Comment: Thanks Master, I anyways got this far with trial and error (I posted the question in July :P). I still face one problem- viewing the content online. The loading goes halfway and then just freezes, specially on IE. I think this should resolve if I set the proper MIME type for viewing the content. Any tips? thanks in advance for answering